# Unable to make basic function in R

Tags: r

A function that gets a list of numbers. The function should return the first x elements of that list such that the sum of the new elements is smaller than 42.

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mo. Please take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You might also look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4752675)

Answer (score 0):

```
list <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
list

get_elements_func <- function(list, max){

    sum_vector <- 0

    for(i in 1:length(list)){

        sum_vector <- rbind(sum_vector, list[[i]])

        if(sum(sum_vector) >= max){

            i <- i - 1
            break
        }
    }

    return(list[1:i])
}

get_elements_func(list, 42)
```

Comment: I know the question says "list of numbers" but I suspect that it's probably just a vector, not a `list`. An answer that assumes a list is going to be overly complex in that case.

Comment: My code will work on a vector if you just change it to `rbind(sum_vector, list[i])` (i.e. single bracket subsetting)

Comment: You've just reinvented `cumsum` I think.

Comment: Haha, fair enough, does cumsum work for lists as well? I think my solution could be more efficient if you are dealing with really large vectors/lists since cumsum will calculate to the end, whereas this will `break` once the max is hit.

Comment: @BigTimeStats I doubt this will be more efficient in most cases as it's not vectorized and repeatedly calling `rbind(sum_vector, list[[i]])` in particular will be very slow - lots of memory reallocation when resizing vectors.